# How to display the names of all controls(textboxes & dropdowns) which are empty in my page

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I get the message Validation Failed if any of my controls are empty, but I would want to display the names of the controls which are empty. These controls are dynamically created on the page.
Below is the code that I am using now

```
   function validateinput() {
      var arrTextBox = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
      var ddlTextBox = document.getElementsByTagName("select");
      var retVal = 1;
      for (i = 0; i < arrTextBox.length; i++) {
          if (arrTextBox[i].type == "text" && arrTextBox[i].getAttribute("IsMandatory") == "Y" && arrTextBox[i].value == ""){
              retVal = 0;
          }
      }

      for (j = 0; j < ddlTextBox.length; j++) {
          if (ddlTextBox[j].getAttribute("IsMandatory") == "Y" && ddlTextBox[j].value == "") {
          retVal = 0;
          }
      }

      if (retVal == 0) {
          alert("Validation Failed");
          return false;
      }
      else {
          alert("Validation Success");
          return true;
      }

  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I see from the comments that you need some more specific assistance.  Try this:

function validateinput() {
      var emptySelects = '';
      var emptyTextboxes = '';
      var arrTextBox = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
      var ddlTextBox = document.getElementsByTagName("select");
      var retVal = 1;
      for (i = 0; i < arrTextBox.length; i++) {
          if (arrTextBox[i].type == "text" && arrTextBox[i].getAttribute("IsMandatory") == "Y" && arrTextBox[i].value == ""){
              retVal = 0;
              emptyTextboxes+= ' ' + arrTextBox[i].name;
          }
      }

```
  for (j = 0; j < ddlTextBox.length; j++) {
      if (ddlTextBox[j].getAttribute("IsMandatory") == "Y" && ddlTextBox[j].value == "") {
      retVal = 0;
      emptySelects += ' ' + ddlTextBox[j].name;
      }
  }

  if (retVal == 0) {
      alert("Validation Failed");
      if (emptyTextboxes != '') alert('The following textboxes are empty:' + emptyTextboxes);
      if (emptySelects != '') alert('The following selections are empty:' + emptySelects);
      return false;
  }
  else {
      alert("Validation Success");
      return true;
  }
```

}

Comment: Yes , I did try this..it does not display the names of all controls in alert box..for every control that is empty , a seperate alert message is displayed...I want something like this alert("The following textboxes are empty ", name1, name2 etc)

Comment: So concatinate a string and check at the end if retval = 0 then alert the string.

Comment: if (arrTextBox[i].type == "text" && arrTextBox[i].getAttribute("IsMandatory") == "Y" && arrTextBox[i].value == ""){
                  retVal = 0;
                  var completestring = new Array();
                  completestring = arrTextBox[i].name;
                  alert(completestring);
                  var temp = new Array();
                  temp = completestring.split(' ');
                  alert(temp); I tried it this way...but not going anywhere